# How to create turtles that create (or are owner of) objects with specific attributes?

Tags: netlogo

The code below should select a random turtle (`selected`) and let it create an object with attributes (`size`, `shape`). `selected` is a local variable, `objects` is a breed; `new_object` and `size` are `objects-own`. 
The reason why I am considering a breed for the objects is that I want to monitor these objects within the network through time. In my code, `size` and `shape` of the object should have the same value of `selected's size` and `shape`. Probably there will be another way to do what I am trying to do, more efficient and correct than mine.

```
  let selected nobody

      set selected one-of turtles with [breed = engineersA or breed = engineersB]
      if empty? [my-list] of selected [
        ask selected [
                set size random-float 1
              ]
                create-objects random 10[
                hide-turtle
                set new_object self
                set size [size] of selected
                set shape [shape] of selected
              ]
              set my-list fput new_object my-list
       ]
```

`new_object` in `my-list` should still keep information about size and shape. 
The schema that I should follow is:

- select a random turtle
- for this turtle, create a new object with specific attributes (size and shape)
- put this object, keeping its attributes, into the turtle's list

Since I have had some issues in plotting the objects (when I want to distinguish between objects created by `engineersA` and objects created by `engineersB`), I wanted to ask your help to better understand how to create turtles that are owner of objects/items.

Any suggestions and/or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what your problem is. But there are three ways to create turtle agents. Look at `create-`, `sprout-` and `hatch-`. In this case, you want `hatch` because that is the way a parent turtle creates a child turtle with the same attribute values. Do `hatch-objects` instead of `create-objects`. That also specifies the breed of the child turtles.

Does this do what you want? It inherits size and shape from the parent and uses `myself` to refer to the parent turtle.

```
ask one-of turtles with [breed = engineersA or breed = engineersB]
[ if empty? my-list
  [ set size random-float 1
  ]
  hatch-objects random 10
  [ hide-turtle
    let this-object self
    ask myself
    [ set my-list fput this-object my-list
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you JenB. I forgot to say that the problem is tin creating turtles that are owners of other objects/turtles. Is it correct to assign the attributes as I did, even using hatch-?

Comment: If you use `hatch` to create the turtles, then the attributes of the child turtle will be the same as the attributes of the parent. So you don't need to explicitly set those values at all.

Comment: Then, it would be more appropriate to associate these attributes within the hatch-, would not it? And, last question, if I add new_object into my-list, this object has the same values of size and shape that I am assigning to the object?

Comment: When I write `if empty? [my-list]` it returns the error "Expected a literal value". Do you know why?

Comment: sorry, should not have had the brackets

Comment: Sorry JenB, but how can I plot the objects depending or the breed that created them? (If you need I can create a new question)

Comment: new question, and also show what you have tried and explain the problem - what is it doing incorrectly?